# How do tall trees transport water at night?

Tags: botany

I was studying transportation in plants and I came across two ways in which plants transport water.

The first one is root pressure. In this method, epiblema cells of root hairs actively absorb minerals from the soil. This creates a concentration gradient of water inside the roots and outside the roots and hence leading to a formation of a column of water. But this method can only be used to transport water for short heights.

In tall trees, the method of transpiration is seen. The evaporation of water molecules from the aerial parts of a plant leads to a phenomenon like a suction pull therefore transporting water.

But in the night, the stomata are closed which means that transpiration can't take place. And root pressure also cannot satisfy the needs of the tree because it is a tall tree.

Then how tall trees transport water in night?

Comment: Welcome Xavier, were expected to show our researches here on biology. Please take the [tour] and refer to the [help] for info as to how we work. Why would the stomata being open during the day enable water to reach heights above that possible by that created by the osmotic gradient at the roots? Ie. what do the stomata have to do with it? Perhaps researching [capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action) might give you an idea about what it is you want to ask, then you can [edit] to clarify a bit.

Comment: Transpiration isnt an yes or no phenomena. The stomata can be opened at various degrees. And transpiration rate depends upon windflow, humidity, sunlight and many other factors. And even if stomata are closed, the cohesion tension bridge will not be lost.